# pointer bringing a conversion error C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to play with arrays and pointers by changing everything back and forth from different values, but this code has brought an error 'cannot convert 'int (*) [4]' to int* in initialization, whats wrong here? no declared properly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int anArray[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    int* firstPnt = &anArray;

    cout << *firstPnt;
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `int* firstPnt = anArray;`

Comment: `&anArray` is of type `int (*)[4]` not `int *`.

Comment: I think the downvotes are a bit harsh. Justification?

Comment: @FredLarson I wish those questions weren't asked here. Everyone rushes here asking why their code doesn't work, and they drown out the real useful questions. I hope those downvotes dissuade at least this guy from coming here **every time his code doesn't compile**.

Comment: yeah wtf is up with the downvoting, that's pretty ignorant

Comment: @TheStache Responding to your (later deleted) comment where you called us "ignorant pricks". I absolutely feel justified downvoting you now, and if you go away, along with your attitude - insulting people you ask questions from, I won't regret it.

Comment: well im sorry but you kind of deserved the remark that was given to you, if you can't handle that I'm sorry but its not my problem

Comment: @TheStache: Regardless of the acceptability of any particular words, name calling is not welcome on SO.

Answer (score 2):

An array decays into pointer of the base type when you refer it by name. However, taking the address of it would give a pointer to the array itself. Do either

```
int (*firstPnt) [4] = &anArray;
```

or

```
int *firstPnt = anArray;
```

The former is a pointer to the whole array, while the latter is a pointer to the first element in the array. When you do `++firstPnt` to the latter, it'll move to the next element i.e. `sizeof(int)` bytes away, while in the former case, it'll move `sizeof(int[4])` bytes away i.e. to the byte next to the last byte of the whole array. So if you want to access the elements, you'd do `(*firstPnt)[0]`, `(*firstPnt)[1]`, etc.

Read [more about array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4810668/183120) to understand this.

Comment: Good answer. It's sometimes difficult to explain these basics.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
int* firstPnt = &anArray[0];
```

or

```
int* firstPnt = anArray;
```

Comment: or `int* firstPnt = &*(anArray+0);`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ampersand.

```
int* firstPnt = anArray;
```